How to typedef one enum type to another?
Here's a minimal example of what I'm trying to do:
enum color { RED, GREEN, BLUE };
typedef enum legacy_color enum color;

int
main(void)
{
    return 0;
}

Compilation fails with
test.c:13:27: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
   13 | typedef enum legacy_color enum color;
      |                           ^~~~
test.c:13:32: warning: empty declaration with storage class specifier does not redeclare tag
   13 | typedef enum legacy_color enum color;
      |                                ^~~~~

Motivation: I need to rename an enum to align with current naming conventions in my project. The old name needs to remain as an alias, which will be declared in a compatibility header file. Referring back to my example, enum color { RED, GREEN, BLUE } will be in the main header file, and typedef enum legacy_color enum color would go in the backward-compatibility header file.
The only other approach I've been able to come up with is #define legacy_color color, but that's overly broad and would match outside the enum type context.
Note that typedef enum color legacy_color; is not acceptable, because the type has changed from enum legacy_color to simply legacy_color.

Apart from macros, which are risky in this context, there's no way to do this.
No way to alias just an enum tag (actually, there's no enum tags, just tags, and the tag namespace is shared between enums, structs and unions, meaning
enum foo conflicts with struct foo and/or union foo but not a plain name foo (variable name or type name; doesn't matter)).
If you want to communicate that a type alias is an enum, you can put the word enum in the type alias's name, e.g., typedef enum legacy_color enum_color;.

That's not how the typedef system in C works.
When you create a typedef name, it has a single identifier, i.e. you can't prefix it with enum or struct.
So if you want to replace enum color with enum legacy_color, then you have some refactoring to do.

Sigh, I was afraid this would be the case.

You have the syntax of typedef backwards. The name being defined comes at the end. You also don't repeat enum. Use
typedef enum color legacy_color;

This will make legacy_color a synonym for the enum you defined on the previous line.
enum color { RED, GREEN, BLUE };
typedef enum color legacy_color;

legacy_color foo = GREEN;
enum color bar = BLUE;

int
main(void)
{
    return 0;
}


Unfortunately that doesn't solve the problem, because that breaks backward compatibiltiy. There is no longer an enum legacy_color type but rather a legacy_color type. I edited the description to make that explicit.

Do it the other way, then. enum legacy_color {...}; typedef enum legacy_color color;

You can't define an enum XXX type in terms of another.
